# WatchOS2 WCSession sendMessage doesn't wake iPhone on background

Tags: ios, watchos-2

This is being tested on both Simulator and real physical device iphone5s. I tried to use WCSession sendMessage to communicate from WatchOS2 extension to iPhone iOS9 code. It works well when iphone app is running either in the foreground and background mode.

But If I kill the iPhone app (not running app at all), then I always got errorHandler timeout. So Watch cannot communicate with iPhone anymore.

> "Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7012 "Message reply took too long."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Message reply took too long.,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Reply timeout occured.}".

I think it supposed to wake iPhone app in the background.

Any idea what to work around this problem or fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Where in the iOS app code are you setting up WCSession?

Comment: I setup in the AppDelegate -init methods. I thought it should be either viewDidLoad in UIViewController or init right?

Comment: Yea, that sounds fine. I'm guessing the message you are sending is quite small? If so, hard to say what could be wrong without all the code. Maybe file a bug with Apple?

Comment: Thanks, I used to use openParentApplication method in WatchOS1, it wake up the iOS app in background no problem. I suspect it is a bug from Apple, but not many people complaining about this though.

Comment: Isn't openParentApplication removed from watchOS 2 ?

Comment: @Eluss yes it is removed.

Comment: Is it possible to wake up iPhone app from watchOS 3 app?

Comment: is it possible to launch iphone app in simulator from watch simulator using sendMessage method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After hours of trying and hint from @jeron. I finally figured out the problem myself.

In my session:didReceiveMessage delegate method, I have two calls. 1.replyHandler call. 2. I have an async process running (RXPromise) in my case, It nested quite a few RXPromise callbacks to fetch various data from cloud service. I didn't pay attention to it, because it is supposed to call and return right away. But now that I commented out RXPromise block all together, it can wake up iOS app in the background every time.

Finally I figure out the trouble make is because after RXPromise call, it is not guaranty to be landed back to main thread anymore. And I believe session:didReceiveMessage has to be return on the main thread. I didn't see this mentioned anywhere on the Apple documentation.

Final solution:

```
- (void)session:(WCSession *)session
    didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message
         replyHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *_Nonnull))replyHandler {

    replyHandler(@{ @"schedule" : @"OK" });

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      Nested RXPromise calls.....
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi @Frank, it's not totally correct that the documentation is not mentioning the threading problem. The header comment for WCSessionDelegate specifies that the delegate callbacks occur on a serial background queue, so this is why you have to switch to main_queue, but all your other info are useful and correct.

Comment: @BootMaker oh thanks for the info. I will take a look.

Answer (score 18):

It is important that you activate the `WCSession` in your `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Also you have to set the `WCSessionDelegate` there. If you do it somewhere else, the code might not be executed when the system starts the killed app in the background.

Also, you are supposed to send the reply via the `replyHandler`. If you try to send someway else, the system waits for a reply that never comes. Hence the timeout error.

Here is an example that wakes up the app if it is killed:

**In the WatchExtension:**

Setup the session. Typically in your ExtensionDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}
```

And then send the message when you need something from the app:

```
if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable {
    let messageDict = ["message": "hello iPhone!"]
    WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(messageDict, replyHandler: { (replyDict) -> Void in
        print(replyDict)
        }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**In the iPhone App:**

Same session setup, but this time also set the delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    ...
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}
```

And then implement the delegate method to send the reply to the watch:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    replyHandler(["message": "Hello Watch!"])
}
```

This works whenever there is a connection between the Watch and the iPhone. If the app is not running, the system starts it in the background.

I don't know if the system waits long enough until you received your data from iCloud, but this example definitely wakes up the app.

Comment: Thanks Joern, I tried exactly your way above as well. It still doesn't launch the ios app in the background. As soon as I open the iOS app, everything start working again. Have you tried kill your iOS app, and try on the watch to see if it is working?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and I get a reply even if the app has been killed.

Comment: Have you tried it by just sending a short text or by fetching something from iCloud?

Comment: Hi @joern, I got it fixed. I answered my own question below. It turns out it is a problem didReceiveMessage method has to return with main thread. Thanks a lot for your help. You affirmation makes me believe it is not Apple's bug and kept me trying different things. Thank you!

Comment: i am recieving message on iphone app  but the message passed in reply handler is not recieved in watch app ..

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `transferUserInfo` in order to queue the calls. Using `sendMessage` will result in errors when app is killed

Comment: My goal actually is to fetch data from Cloud through iPhone, for various reason, I cannot use NSUrlSession from WatchExtension directly. Therefore, I want  sendmessage to wake up iPhone, request data from cloud then use transferUserInfo to send back the data to the Watch.