# watchOS2 app and iPhone app communication

Tags: iphone, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

In the watchOS1, we had a method “openParentApplication”. This method communicated with the phone application even when it wasn’t running in foreground or background and fetched a reply immediately. I need something similar for watchOS2. I want my watch application to communicate immediately with the phone app even if my iPhone application is not running. Methods like `updateApplicationContext:error:`, `sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:` and `transferUserInfo:` are not helpful in this scenario.

Please can someone suggest me a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: I was looking for the same solution for some time but I couldn't find anything that could fit my needs. There was similar topic here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136536/watchos2-wcsession-sendmessage-doesnt-wake-iphone-on-background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:` is doing exactly what you are asking for. As long as your watch is connected to your phone it immediately gets a response to the message. This is working when the app is in the foreground, in the background or not running at all.

Here is how you set it up:

**In the WatchExtension:**

Setup the session. Typically in your ExtensionDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}
```

And then send the message when you need something from the app:

```
if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable {
    let messageDict = ["message": "hello iPhone!"]
    WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(messageDict, replyHandler: { (replyDict) -> Void in
        print(replyDict)
        }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**In the iPhone App:**

Same session setup, but this time also set the delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    ...
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}
```

And then implement the delegate method to send the reply to the watch:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    replyHandler(["message": "Hello Watch!"])
}
```

This works whenever there is a connection between the Watch and the iPhone. If the app is not running, the system starts it in the background. So, basically it just works like `openParentApplication(_:reply:)`